# Parse String into @StringDef interface

Tags: android

I have the following @StringDef interface defined:

```
@StringDef({MODEL_US, MODEL_CA, MODEL_MX})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface DeviceModel {
}
```

And I am trying to parse a String into a `DeviceModel` object but am struggling to understand how to do that.  Any ideas?

Comment: How did you do it?

Comment: I don't believe I found a solution to this.